# 編集履歴に表示されるタイトル差分にセミコロンが混入するバグ

Tags: バグ

[こちらの質問の編集履歴](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/35675/revisions) #2 において、タイトルの差分に余計なセミコロン `;` が混入しています。

もしかしたら不等号 `<`, `>` 周りと関連するバグかもしれないと思い、一応投稿いたします。

以下がスクリーンショットです。 "question about opencv" が ";questions about opencv" になっています。

[image: 編集履歴のスクリーンショット]

---

If you look at the [edit history of this question](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/35675/revisions) then you will notice that in the title there is a stray semi-colon. It may be possible that this is related to the use of `<` or `>`. See the screenshot below:

[image: 編集履歴のスクリーンショット]